# Passing simple string from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Inside `Form1` I have a combobox `cmbDataList`. On user select I want to use this selection to pass that selection text to the form so I use the following code:

**Form1.cs**

```
private void cmbDataList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   selectedOption = (ICustomData)cmbDataList.SelectedItem;            
   Form2 frm2 = new Form2() { SelectedData = selectedOption.ToString() };
}
```

Inside `Form2` I have a `SelectedData` property which should receive passed option text from `Form1`

**Form2.cs**

```
public string SelectedData { get; set; }

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    txtSelectedData.Text = SelectedData ;                      
}
```

On loading `txtSelectedData.Text` is empty, it's not populated with string value.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the code for `Show()` of the form ?

Comment: Show()? please add more details

Comment: Have you verified that `selectedOption.ToString()` actually returns anything?

Comment: yes, I am, with debugging selectedOption is populated

Comment: @pajo my explanation was not correct, because I thought you are using constructor to set selected data text. Can you add to question code, which shows Form2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `SelectedData` property definition from auto-generated to one which sets and returns text of `txtSelectedData` textbox:

```
public string SelectedData 
{ 
  get { return txtSelectedData.Text; } 
  set { txtSelectedData.Text = value; } 
}
```

**UPDATE** your current code should work if you will show form just after creation:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2() { SelectedData = selectedOption.ToString() };
frm2.Show(); // here
```

Comment: Not sure but won't the load event be fired when the form is shown, so it should set the value ? the assignment is not part of the constructor

Comment: @V4Vendetta ah, thanks. For unknown reason I thought it was constructor. Actually `Load` is fired before form is shown first time. I'll update answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the selecteddata to the form2 constructor.

so modify the form 2 constructoo like this

```
public form2(String SelectedData){
 txtSelectedData.Text = SelectedData ; 
}
```

and when creating an instance of form2, pass the value like this

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2(selectedOption.ToString());
```